# Executing sequence of functions that return a future sequentially

Tags: scala, twitter-util

I have a sequence of functions that return a future. I want to execute them sequentially i.e. after the first function future is complete, execute the next function and so on. Is there a way to do it?

ops: Seq[() => Future[Unit]]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine all the futures into a single one with a `foldLeft` and `flatMap`:

```
def executeSequentially(ops: Seq[() => Future[Unit]])(
  implicit exec: ExecutionContext
): Future[Unit] =
  ops.foldLeft(Future.successful(()))((cur, next) => cur.flatMap(_ => next()))
```

`foldLeft` ensures the order from left to right and `flatMap` gives sequential execution. Functions are executed with the `ExecutionContext`, so calling `executeSequentially` is not blocking. And you can add callbacks or await on the resulting `Future` when/if you need it.

If you are using Twitter `Future`s, then I guess you won't need to pass `ExecutionContext`, but the general idea with `foldLeft` and `flatMap` should still work.

Answer (score 2):

If given a Seq[Future[T]] you can convert it to a Future[Seq[T]] like so:

```
Val a: Seq[Future[T]] = ???

val resut: Future[Seq[T]] = Future.sequence(a)
```

a little less boilerplate than the above :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should do it:

```
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

def runSequentially(ops: Seq[() => Future[Unit]]): Unit = {
  ops.foreach(f => Await.result(f(), Duration.Inf))
}
```

If you want to wait less then `Duration.Inf`, or stop at failure - should be easy to do.